# Is it possible to hide some part of message in iOS Notification?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, notifications

I am sending "Push Notification" from Amazon SNS to iOS devices. While sending a notification, i want to hide the url and to show remaining string in notification to the user.

> For Instance :
>
> Notification is like this "Hi customers
>   https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=zCyeVbuiMZK_-APxlYHoBA welcome"
>
> Show the notification to the user as "Hi customers welcome"
>
> And i want to store the entire notification message in database.
>
> If user clicks on notification then i have to open that link in embedded browser. But that url will not be visible to the user

Is it possible to hide some part of message in notification ? Advance thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you need the link anyway? If you explain it, we might give you a better solution than "just don't include it".

Comment: If user clicks on notification then i have to open that link in embedded browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html):

> Providers can specify custom payload values outside the Apple-reserved aps namespace. Custom values must use the JSON structured and primitive types: dictionary (object), array, string, number, and Boolean. You should not include customer information (or any sensitive data) as custom payload data. [...]

An example is provided in the documentation:

```
{
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received from Bob" },
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

In your case I suggest a payload like this:

```
{
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Welcome Customers!" },
    "welcome-url" : "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=zCyeVbuiMZK_-APxlYHoBA"
}
```